# dpkg binaries broken?

Tags: dpkg

I bought a new Raspberry Pi 2 with ARM processor architecture. Tonight I did an update via `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. I noticed, that it did update the dpkg package itself.

Now I wanted to install apache2 on the Raspbian system, but the dpkg binaries seem to be broken:

```
...
/usr/bin/dpkg-deb: 1: /usr/bin/dpkg-deb: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-data_2.4.10-10+deb8u3_all.deb (--unpack):
 Unterprozess dpkg-deb --control gab den Fehlerwert 2 zurück
...
```

For all none german speakers

"Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs" means "An error occurred while processing the archive" and means "Unterprozess dpkg-deb --control gab den Fehlerwert 2 zurück" the "Subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error code 2"

This happens to all packages I'm trying to install.

What can I do now?

Comment: It's a raspberry pi 2 running Raspbian (Debian) Jessy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restore the binaries without using `dpkg`, here's the "simple" approach, assuming your Raspberry Pi has `binutils` installed:

- retrieve the `dpkg` package (the `.deb` file); it's probably still in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, otherwise you'll need to download it (from [the pool](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/d/dpkg/); pick whichever version matches what you have installed)
- extract the `data.tar.gz` file from the archive, somewhere safe: `ar x dpkg_....deb data.tar.gz`
- extract `dpkg-deb`: `tar xf data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg-deb`
- move `dpkg-deb` into place: `sudo mv usr/bin/dpkg-deb /usr/bin`

If you don't have `binutils` installed, you'll need to extract `data.tar.gz` on another computer (after installing `binutils` there if necessary).

Comment: Yes, i found it too. For everyone with the same problem (Raspberry PI 2, Raspbian Jessy), use the file: http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.26_armhf.deb. I followed your instructions and it's working. THANKS!

Comment: Be aware there are too many reports about corrupted and failed MicroSD cards. This time you managed to salvage your work. Keep several MicroSD cards at hand, and have always a recent backup.